# How to force validation of UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, user-controls

Validations for my textbox controls work normally/as expected. However, for my created `UserControl`, also containing a textbox (which also contains other controls as well), it's not always validated, except when the user manually selects/focuses another control, which will of course fire the `Validating` event.

Now, I've found from searches about [`Form.ValidateChildren()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.validatechildren?view=netframework-4.7.2) (**which works btw**), but this method validates all children as described in the documentation, which is not the ideal solution to a form with many controls, as opposed to only validating the single control in question.

Additional info:

1. I use `ErrorProvider` to show errors - I need to consider the position
   of the icon in the case of my `UserControl` (which again, contains
   multiple controls inside).
2. `Validating` and `Validated` events are performed on my `UserControl`, **not** the TextBox inside it. Both events are on the form where the usercontrol is used.
3. The `Text` property of the `TextBox` inside my `UserControl` is modified
   internally (inside my `UserControl` class)

`

```
//some code inside usercontrol
private void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    textBox.Text = ...;
    ParentForm.ValidateChildren();    // works but does this on all controls which is not the ideal operation, which is to perform validation only on this usercontrol
}
```

`

With the above-mentioned info, when I modify the `Text` property manually, the Validating event is, as expected on the design, not raised since `UserControl.TextBox` != `UserControl`. It's not an option for me to perform validation on the `UserControl.TextBox` instead of the `UserControl`.

With all that explained, how should I manually/forcefully trigger the validation **only** for the `UserControl`, when `UserControl.TextBox.Text` is modified, without resorting to `Form.ValidateChildren` which targets all of the form controls? Or is it not possible?

Comment: UserControls have a [ValidateChildren()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.validatechildren) method as well.

Comment: As described in the question, the control I need to validate is the `UserControl` itself, not its children.

Comment: Call `UserControl.Validate()` then. If the UC has unvalidated controls, overriding `OnValidating` will *intercept* it. No matter if `AutoValidate` is disabled.

Comment: Tried calling Validate() for UserControl, did not work though. I wonder what is further needed for this to work.

Comment: I don't know what *did not work* means. Did you change *something* in some child control? If you don't change anything, `OnValidating` is not called.

Comment: Did not work, considering this question, means validation was not raised when I tried calling **`Validate()`** in place of **`Form.ValidateChildren()`**. As for the process of raising the validation, please refer again to the explanations in the actual question.

Comment: *how should I manually/forcefully trigger the validation only for the UserControl*. Call `UserControl.Validate()`. In the UC you are, of course, overriding `OnValidating`. If the property value of some controls has changed, `OnValidating` will be called. If nothing has changed, `OnValidating` won't be called. If this is not what you're looking for, then try to explain why it's not.

Comment: I will just be repeating the explanation **already** provided above. I modify the `Text` property inside my usercontrol class. And in my reply comment to your suggestion to call the `Validate()` method, I tried using it in place of `Form.ValidateChildren()`. `OnValidating` event was not raised, unlike in `Form.ValidateChildren()`, which obviously fires the `OnValidating` event. My issue however, is if there is a way to do this **only for a single control**, and not calling `Form.ValidateChildren()` because it does this for all controls inside it.

Comment: So, you're saying that, you changed the Text of a child control inside a UserControl, then you called `UserControl.Validate()` and something like this (in the UC):  `protected override void OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e) { base.OnValidating(e); MessageBox.Show("Validating"); }` didn't pop a MessageBox? Hard to believe. Make a new UC with just a TextBox inside and test it.

Comment: No, I would not perform validation inside the usercontrol itself, since its main purpose is to be used on another usercontrol, or a form. Validation is performed (`Validated` and `Validating` events) in the form.

Immediately after I modify `TextBox.Text` value inside the usercontrol, I call `Form.ValidateChildren()` (still on the usercontrol), which I'm trying to ask for alternatives which will perform validation only for my usercontrol, which raises the validation events.